# Specified query type "Query" not found in document when deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, graphql, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy a `typescript-graphql-postgres` server onto heroku. The build was successful, however, when run I get the following from heroku logs:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Specified query type "Query"
>   not found in document. 2018-11-08T08:54:52.660051+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   /app/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:184:15

Anyone encountered and know the fix?

btw, when I run on my computer, the code works

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I need to copy graphql files into the relevant modules folders

below is what I added to my package.json for those who run into the same issue

```
  "build": "rimraf dist && tsc && copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.graphql dist",
```